# What are all those parameters in an Amazon affiliate/associate link?

Tags: parameters, affiliate

I've found this link, I was wondering what were all those parameters in the URL (removed the `&` and broke them into separate lines for readability):

> [https://www.amazon.com/Backseat-Organizer-Protector-Storage-Organizers/dp/B071Y6F4SR/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071Y6F4SR)
>
> ref=as_li_ss_tl    ---> This seems to be in every Amazon affiliate link
>
> smid=A2AMCOIC0OKFCA    ---> Is this the product category ID?
>
> pf_rd_p=695f29ac-ec28-4005-ae23-4a6ff667d724
>
> pf_rd_s=slot-4
>
> pf_rd_t=701
>
> pf_rd_i=gb_main
>
> pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER
>
> pf_rd_r=1Z9QWS8H760T7QX98SV2
>
> linkCode=sl1
>
> tag=xxxxxxx-20     ---> This is the ID for the Amazon affiliate, who's posted the link
>
> linkId=96f85c1971c0eb3edcf31e3faf903aea
>
> utm_content=buffer9bbb8
>
> utm_medium=social
>
> utm_source=twitter.com   ---> The original link was posted to Twitter, so I guess this is for tracking and metrics
>
> utm_campaign=buffer     ---> This seems to indicate that the message originated from buffer social media tool

Answer (score 4):

for only information on  that this all data are relates to your affiliate campaign or not?then answer is NOT. following is the explanation.
there is also simplest amazon affiliate link,i don't know other parameter all listed but i can sure about that they are unrelaevent to the affiliate because the following is my valid affiliate link

```
https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B002GZX2DE/?tag=XXXXXX-20
```

B002GZX2DE is product code.
and this link is in amazon affiliate url cheker it is valid  also.